# Javascript setting iframe src not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I set the iframe source using javascript it doesn't work. The first alert message shows up as the data-src of the iframe, but the second shows up empty.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var slide = images.item(i);

  slide.style.src = slide.dataset.src;
  alert(slide.dataset.src);

  alert(slide.style.src);
}
```

```html
<iframe class="load color light" data-type="src" width="865" height="572" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ONA67lhVpLs?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: `style` changes the `stylesheet` of the element. Use `slide.src` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slide.src` instead of `slide.style.src`.

You want to set the HTML attribute `element.src`, `element.style.src` sets a CSS property `src`, which isn't setting the iframe src. Read more about the CSS property `src` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src).

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property is for changing CSS properties.
`src` is an HTML attribute.

Try using this :

```js
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let slide = images.item(i);
  slide.setAttribute("src", slide.dataset.src);
  alert(slide.dataset.src);

  alert(slide.getAttribute("src"));
}
```